# Do not truncate parameters in debug backtrace logs

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, monolog

Using Laravel, I sometimes get errors. These errors are logged into a file (`laravel.log`) with their backtrace. I use a small log viewer I built to analyze it. The problem is parameters in function are truncated. Example:

```
#2[internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\AController->show('97773dc2-6a57-4...')
```

Can I expand this? Is there something to do with error handler?

Comment: Try increasing the `zend.exception_string_param_max_len` PHP option